# How to create dll from app source in c++ builder 6?

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder-6

I have legacy code in C++Builder 6. I try to create a DLL from source code, but only one thing which I have on output is an EXE. I tried to change the application target extension and entry point, but nothing helps.

I think about compiling from console, but there is some errors in the project, that I can't see when compiling in the IDE. I have linker errors, which I can't fix.

At least all code are `"extern C"` and I need `lib` and `dll`.

How can I compile a DLL from the app source?

Comment: There are changes required to turn an executable project to a DLL library project. It's not a simple matter of just recompiling the same source unless  the author specifically designed it that way.

Comment: ***How can I compile it from app source?*** This is not going to be a simple compiler switch. You will have to spend some time understanding how a dll is built with your toolchain and several days (or longer depending on the code and your understanding of how it works) to port the old code into a dll. There may also be other considerations if you plan to use the dll with a different toolchain other than c++builder.

Comment: Hmmph. app have some Forms, i disable it, and disable sockets. At leats I think that I can change something in .bpl fil and convert it, but it not work too. Well I think to try copy it bit-by-bit in new project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DLL` needs certain pre-defined functions and the project Wizard creates them for you automatically, so

- Start a new fresh project as a DLL/library project.
- Create a simple function that you can test.
- Compile the `DLL` and load it (and call the test function) from an `.exe` in another project to check that it's working.
- Copy the essential parts of your old code, bit by bit, from the old `.exe` project into the correct places in the new DLL/library project.

Done.